Is there a way to open apps like whatsapp from react web app?
I have a share button on my react  app,when someone clicks it, i want the share pop up to come up on the web app  and share the link on any mobile app
i wanted to implement it using intent links, but all articles say about react-native

Solution : URL Schemes
Code
const ShareButton = () => {
  const handleShareClick = () => {
    const textToShare = encodeURIComponent(
      'Check out this awesome link: https://example.com'
    );
    const whatsappUrl = `whatsapp://send?text=${textToShare}`;
    window.location.href = whatsappUrl;
  };

  return <button onClick={handleShareClick}>Share on WhatsApp</button>;
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>My React App</h1>
      <ShareButton />
    </div>
  );
}

You can use URL Schemes, Adding screenshot to show how it opens whatsapp either in phone or macos.

If you click on Open Whatsapp, it opens whatsapp and show screen that asks for contacts to send this text.

choose contacts on whatsapp
click send.


can you try this? If you are in mobile browser, this will open whatsapp app on your phone. If you are in desktop browser it will open whatsapp web url
const shareURL = "https://www.codewithmilan.com" // or any url
   <a key={name} href=`https://wa.me/?text=${shareURL}` target="_blank" 
    rel="noreferrer">
     WhatsApp Share Button
   </a>

